# On a partner community, can I give access to hierarchy accounts to view the child related records?

Tags: partner-communities

In our partner community, we have private oppty sharing rules, and sharing sets that grant access based on : opportunity.partnerid = accountid

We have scenarios, where the accounts have a hierarchy, and in these scenarios, we want to also give access to the parent account for it's subsidieries opptys as well. The sharing set does not work, since the accountid is different than the oppty.partnerid.

The hierarchy is unknown, thus can be multiple levels.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can give access to parent account to see opportunities of child accounts by using external account heirarchy feature but it's cannot be disabled once it's enabled